# Predict the products of the following reactions with Mechanism

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, rearrangements

> [image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W55CW.png)

**My Attempt** : The correct answer is C. I tried rearranging similar to claisen rearrangement but I have no clue how to go forward. I know that option A is wrong and that the product is pretty easily predictable.
But I cannot predict either the product or the mechanism.***A detailed solution for each reaction  would be very helpful.***
Thank you.

Comment: fyi (D) gives pyrazole. It is known as the Pechmann pyrazole synthesis  https://www.drugfuture.com/OrganicNameReactions/onr296.htm

Comment: It's hard for me to imagine that (C) does not take place at some level.

Comment: Can you imagine that C takes part to form something?

Comment: Unlikely that B is the correct answer because of the oxidation state. Loss of acetic acid gives a nitrile but there is no way to add acetate to the ring. The oxime of benzaldehyde is dehydrated with Ac2O to benzonitile and acetic acid, i. e., the intermediate is B's starting material. C, as @Zhe has suggested, is the likely answer.

Comment: Ok then Guys,I have edited my question to C being the answer,I'll accept it if you can give some mechanism predicting each product.

Comment: I think we have helped you enough. As to a mechanism for C, I suggest you Google thermolysis (pyrolysis) of esters.